# www prefix on subdomain

Tags: subdomain

I have a domain mydomain.com. both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com resove to same shared IP computer and working find. I have created a subdomain sub.mydomain.com and directed to another static IP. How can I resolve www.sub.mydomain.com to same ip as sub.mydomain.com ?

I have plesk control panel for dns management.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a new subdomain called www.sub.mydomain.com and direct it to the same IP that sub.mydomain.com has. Or create an CNAME record and point www.sub.mydomain.com to sub.mydomain.com.